# discord.py rewrite - getting Permissions of a discord.Member

Tags: python, discord, attributeerror, discord.py

I am trying to get permissions of a mentioned discord.Member
I have tried it with

```
if discord.utils.get(user.guild_permissions, name="manage_messages"):
```

where **user: discord.Member**
and I get this error

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for permissions, you can use the `discord.Permissions` object's attributes. To check for the `manage messages` permission, you would do

```
if <permissions object>.manage_messages:
    #bot's code
```

In your case, the permissions object would be `user.guild_permissions`

A full list of attributes for the permissions object can be found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissions)